# Flutter redux_logging logging only Instance of 'AppState' instead of AppState value

Tags: flutter, logging, redux

I am new with Flutter. I added this package to my Redux https://pub.dev/packages/redux_logging

However, the output I get is

```
[INFO] LoggingMiddleware: {Action: Instance of 'SetSomeStateAction', State: Instance of 'AppState', ts: 2020-10-25 15:39:05.708}
```

instead of the value of the state. Is this how it is supposed to go? Thank you

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't. @KrasnokutskiyEA

Answer (score 0):

The toString method has to be overridden for both the state and Actions. The state's toString should return what you want to see in the state. The Actions could return its class runtimeType and details of its variables, as required.